# Function() argument 'code' must be code, not str

Tags: python, ursina

I am trying to use the [ursina](https://pypi.org/project/ursina/) module, and just entered this code:

```
from ursina import *

class Game(Ursina):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

It generates this error:

```
>>> from ursina import *
>>> class Game(Ursina):
>>> ...     def __init__(self):
>>> ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<test>", line 3, in <module>
class Game(Ursina):
TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

I have no `code` argument, so I have no clue what this is referring to.

Can someone explain and fix this error?

Comment: What is `ursina`?

Comment: You're probably trying to subclass a function. Try running `print(type(Ursina))`.

Comment: This can happen when there's a syntax error or incorrect indentation in your code.

Comment: Looks like you are doing this in a REPL.  you need to provide the full context of what you are trying.   As noted.  we need to know more about the code referenced in your snippet.  please edit your question and add that detail.

Comment: I could reproduce this with just the code that the asker provided. Seems to be a problem with the `ursina` module? (BTW, `Ursina` is a class)

Comment: @trincot `Ursina` is not a class.

Comment: @interjay, [it is](https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/blob/master/ursina/main.py#L24), but decorated as singleton, as you correctly answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Ursina [issue 579](https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/issues/579).

This is a limitation of the Ursina package which doesn't let you subclass the `Ursina` class.

The `Ursina` class is defined as:

```
@singleton
class Ursina(ShowBase):
    ...
```

And `singleton` is:

```
def singleton(cls, **kwargs):
    def getinstance(**kwargs):
        if not hasattr(cls, '_instance') or not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = cls(**kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    return getinstance
```

This means that the decorated `Ursina` is actually the function returned by `singleton` rather than a class, and so it can't be subclassed.

Comment: It's ugly, but you can extract the original class from `Ursina` with `Ursina.__closure__[0].cell_contents`.